# How do I remove the CSS property after clicking the second time with jquery .click function?

Tags: jquery, css, click, background-color

The CSS properties are added after the first click, but I need them to go away after the second click. What am I missing?

I tried doing it with `toggle()` and `removeClass()`, but I'm not experienced enough...

```js
if ($(window).width() < 800) {
  $('.dropdown').hide();
  $('.fa-bars').click(function() {
    $("ul").css("background-color", "white");
    $('.dropdown').slideToggle();
  })
}
```

Comment: Put the `background-color: white` style in to a class, then use `toggleClass()` instead

Comment: There *has* to be a good dupetarget for this... Haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet here is not to use the `css` function at all. Instead, use a class, and toggle it:

CSS:

```
.toggled {
    background-color: white;
    /* Perhaps add an animation here if you want the slide toggle look */
}
```

JavaScript:

```
if ($(window).width() < 800) {
  $('.dropdown').hide();
  $('.fa-bars').click(function() {
    $("ul").toggleClass("toggled"); // ***
  })
}
```

---

That entire JavaScript block would probably be better suited to a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) that hides the dropdown on screen widths below 800, and then just the click event handler to show it even when the screen width is below 800.

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    .dropdown:not(.show) {
        display: none;
        /* Perhaps add an animation here if you want the slide toggle look */
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.fa-bars').click(function() {
  $("ul").toggleClass("show");
})
```